# Can allied teammates build cities in each other's territory?

Tags: freeciv

I'm playing multiplayer Freeciv. I'm on a team with another player, plus we have an alliance. I'd like to build a city in his territory.

This had been possible recently, I think. We have Freeciv 2.3.4 now, and pressing <kbd>b</kbd> has no effect. No error message shows up when pressing <kbd>b</kbd> either. "Build" in the menu bar is grayed-out for that settler.

Is there any workaround, or an option we missed? Or has this "feature" just been removed from the game by an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can only build on terrain owned by your own nation, the question is how to get new terrain.

You can build a fort pressing <kbd>f</kbd>. Then, the fort, and (sometimes) some terrain around it, will be set to your country. I think taking over a foreign fort has even the same effect. This new terrain is suited to build you city.

I found this out by chance. The official handbook, [freeciv.wikia.com](http://freeciv.wikia.com/wiki/Combat#Cities_and_Forts), does not mention this, though. It might be a bug, but it is perfectly working.